# 2 image size for post

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have servel image sizes in my post, all under 2 proportion: square  and  rectangle.

for example
square  :100X100, 200X200
rectangle: 300X100, 600X200

Via ACF I created new image upload file so I can upload one proportion via ACF and one proportion via 'post-thumbnails'

How can I control add_image_size function so the rectangle resize will make from the rectangle file and the square  resizes will make from the square  size

Answer (score 0):

WP image sizes apply to all images - there's no way to tell WP, "only generate rectangular sizes when I upload a rectangular image; and only generate square sizes when I upload a square image." So, you need to add (or customize an existing) image size for each scenario.

Comment: any way to tell WP what image to use each proportion ?

Comment: Yes, you can set cropping, so you can control whether it pulls from the center of the image, top left, etc. This article explains it nicely - https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/wordpress-thumbnail-crop